# Polymer Acceder a evento de custom-element en otra pagina

Tags: polymer

Me pregunto si saben como acceder a los metodos de custom-element invocados en otra pagina. Por ejemplo ejecutar desde `my-app.html` el evento `openDrawer()`
de `paper-drawer-panel` que haya sido invocado en otra pagina en una `iron-page`
tomando encuenta que se esta usando el **starter-kit** de Polymer

Answer (score 0):

Para comunicar dos páginas puedes utilizar [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/WebSockets-840092-dup/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications). Tendrias que create tus propios custom-elements que implementasen esa funcionalidad

Comment: Mi duda es la siguiente: existe una manera nativa para ejecutarlo con un elemento de polymer?

Comment: Nativa no. Pero hay custom-elements que te pueden ayudar [http://hph.is/web-socket/](http://hph.is/web-socket/) - [https://customelements.io/search/websockets](https://customelements.io/search/websockets)

Answer (score 0):

No creo debas usar web sockets si lo único que quieres es ejecutar la función de un componente en el Javascript puentes acceder al componente y ejecutar su método tal cual, por lo que entiendo si usas iron-pages tienes un componente que funciona como el punto de entrada de tu aplicación ahí en el código js de ese componente puedes acceder a los métodos de los componentes usados.